# RelativeLayout with ListView doesn't shown properly

Tags: android, listview, android-relativelayout

I'm going crazy trying to make an relative layout work. I was getting an problem with ListView, the listView always show an empty space with approximately, twice the height of one listView element, independent if the list is big enough to scroll or not (usually the list accommodate 4 elements without the need of scroll).

To solve that, I'm trying to implement an RelativeLayout. I have One TextView at the top, and one at the bottom, and my listview is in the middle. The textView's must be "glued" on my listview, I was using LinearLayout before the empty space problem, and now I have this Relative Layout:

```
    <ScrollView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:background="@drawable/background"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent">

     <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     ...
            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+datatrade/tv_itens"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="Itens:" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+datatrade/tv_value"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Value:" />                                        

                <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200px"
                    android:layout_below="@datatrade/tv_itens"
                    android:layout_above="@datatrade/tv_value"
                    android:id="@+id/list_product"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>
     ...
```

The problem is, that I just get my second text view shown, with "values: ", and nothing else!
All the rest of the relative layout is just ignored by android!

Does anyone know what can be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+datatrade/tv_value"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Value:" />
```

you have not declared where this textview should be displayed.

Comment: I tried with android:layout_alignParentTop="true" in my textView without position declared (this one) and everything still like it was, only this textView is shown.

Comment: sorry my question.. do you wanna add header and footer to the listview?

Comment: then you add alread something with android:layout_alignParentTop="true" . Did you tried android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" ?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forget that alignParentTop. I tried with alignParentBottom and I get the same result...

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify each object to be related to each other.Otherwise there is no way that relative layout would understand where you position the object and there will be no relativity.

Check this to understand the relativity between objects and how to position them

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#CCE6FF">

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01"    android:id="@+id/dialog_desc_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:textSize="18dip" android:textColor="#000000"/>

</ScrollView>

<Button android:id="@+id/dialog_goToDesc_button"  android:layout_below="@id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Satın Al" />

<Button android:id="@+id/dialog_buy_button" android:layout_below="@id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dialog_goToDesc_button" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Detaya git" />

<Button android:id="@+id/dialog_cancel_button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dialog_buy_button" android:layout_below="@id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Kapat" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_itens"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="Itens:" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_value"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Value:" 
                    android:layout_below="@+id/list_product"/>                                        

                <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_itens"
                    android:id="@+id/list_product"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You need to tell the ListView to be below the first TextView and then the second TextView to be below the ListView.

Also your id's seem a bit wierd, I got a warning when I copied your code, try using @+id to be sure.

Finally you shouldn't use px as a size, instead use dp which is relative.